# My website is marked as a phising website

Tags: reactjs, web, firebase-hosting

Can someone tell me why my facebook-clone is marked as phising website?
I don't have any intension of phising.
Is it because of the google authentification or because it's a copy of Facebook?
https://fb-clone-30188.web.app/

Comment: Because your website acts exactly like a phising website. Chrome doesn't know your intention, and no one knows what would happen if someone actually tries to login with there actual Facebook account and password.

Comment: Don't try to host this type of learning project online, it will automatically detect by the crawler and it will be converted to a phishing website.

Comment: If I'm going to remove the login process will it fix my problem?

Comment: It's probably because of this free hosting that you are using. Better use heroku or github pages